# How to select in select by Linq (Entity framework)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I using entity framework for my database and select or/and include revealing so many data so basically i'm looking for query like this:

```
var result = DbContext.products
            .select(p=> new {
             p.Id,
             p.Name,
             p.Notes
             .select(n=> new {
                n.date,
                n.text
                             }
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var result = DbContext.products
        .select(p=> new {
                         Id = p.Id,
                         Name = p.Name,
                         SelectedNodes = p.Notes.select(n=> 
                                             new {n.date, n.text}).ToList()                            
        });
```